# how to use array inside array in knockoutjs jQuery template

Tags: jquery, templates, knockout.js

I am not able to read arrays inside another array with knockoutjs jquery template below is the code lines. Please help.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
ko.applyBindings({
    lines: [
        { line: 'Anshul', links: [{link:'Add'},{link:'Remove'}] },
        { line: 'ABC', links: [{link:'Add'},{link:'Cancel'}]},
        { line: 'XYZ', links: [{link:'Add'},{link:'Remove'},{link:'Cancel'}] }
    ]
});
```

```
<table>
<tbody data-bind="template: { name: 'personTemplate'}" ></tbody>
</table>


<script type="text/x-jquery-tmpl" id="personTemplate">
{{each lines}}
<tr><td>${line}</td>
```

NOW HERE FOR EACH LINES I WANT TO DISPLAY LIST OF LINKS . but i am facing issue in doing so

Thanks,
Anshul Kaistha

Comment: what version of knockout are you using?

Comment: You can use `$data` to refer to the current data that you are bound against, which will be the `lines` array.  Otherwise, you if you want your template to be executed for each item, then you can use the `foreach` parameter to the template binding.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick jsfiddle using the native knockout template engine:

http://jsfiddle.net/2ywc6/

Note that the only difference here is the actual template code, the JS view model is the same.

Comment: i need to do it in knockout jQuery template. i am using knockout version 1.3.0